# Find the isolated singularities of the function and calculate their residues

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, singularity

Find the isolated singularities of $\dfrac{3z}{z^3+1}$ and calculate their residues using the 'g/h rule'

I understand that $z=-1$ is a singularity but I'm not sure about the others or how to apply the gh rule to this function.

Comment: For the residue, we need the (complex!) solutions to the equation $z^3+1 = 0$, or $z^3 = -1 = e^{\pi i +2 \pi k}$. Can you solve this? If not, try to see what happens in the case for $z^2+1 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

$$z^3=-1\implies z^3=e^{i(2n-1)\pi}$$

for $n=0,1,2$.

Alternatively, write $z^3+1=(z-1)(z^2+z+1)$ and find the roots of the quadratic.

Comment: I see why it has to be 2n-1 as it is for odd values that e^{pi*i}=-1 but I have the answer to be z=+\- e^{i*pi\3} and still not sure how to get this?

Comment: Sophie, that is a good question.  Note that $e^{-i\pi/3}=e^{i5\pi/3}$ due to the $2\pi$-periodicity of $e^{i\theta}$.  -Mark

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really just want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark